# How do you track the location of PDPageContentStream's text output?

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am using Java to write output to a `PDDocument`, then appending that document to an existing one before serving it to the client.

Most of it is working well. I only have a small problem trying to handle content overflow while writing to that `PDDocument`.
I want to keep track of where text is being inserted into the document so that when the "cursor" so to speak goes past a certain point, I'll create a new page, add it to the document, create a new content stream, and continue as normal.

Here is some code that shows what I'd like to do:

```
// big try block
PDDocument doc = new PDDocument();
PDPage page = new PDPage();
doc.addPage(page);
PDPageContentStream content = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page);
int fontSize = 12;

content.beginText();
content.setFont(...);
content.moveTextPositionByAmount(margin, pageHeight-margin);
for ( each element in a collection of values ) {
    content.moveTextPositionByAmount(0, -fontSize); // only moves down in document

    // at this point, check if past the end of page, if so add a new page
    if (content.getTextYPosition(...) < margin) { // wishful thinking, doesn't exist
        content.endText();
        content.close();
        page = new PDPage();
        doc.addPage(page);
        content = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page);
        content.beginText();
        content.setFont(...);
        content.moveTextPositionByAmount(margin, pageHeight-(margin+fontSize));
    }
    content.drawString(...);
}
content.endText();
content.close();
```

The important bit is the `content.getTextYPosition()`. It doesn't actually exist, but I'm sure `PDPageContentStream` must be keeping track of a similar value. Is there any way to access this value?

Thanks.

Comment: *I'm sure PDPageContentStream must be keeping track of a similar value* - it doesn't.

Comment: How can it not keep track of it somewhere? How would it remember where to continue outputting text?

Comment: `PDPageContentStream` does not need to remember: All it does in this context is write the commands you give into a stream in the PDF. The interpretation of those commands is done by the PDF viewer. Thus, only the PDF viewer needs to keep track of it, not PDFBox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a `heightCounter` variable that tracks how far you've moved the text location. It's initial value can be your starting Y position.

```
        PDRectangle mediabox = page.findMediaBox();
        float margin = 72;
        float width = mediabox.getWidth() - 2 * margin;
        float startX = mediabox.getLowerLeftX() + margin;
        float startY = mediabox.getUpperRightY() - margin;
        float heightCounter = startY;
```

Every time you move the text position, subtract that from your `heightCounter`. When `heightCounter` is less than what you're moving the text position by, then create a new page.

Comment: Oop, yea that's essentially what I ended up doing. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
        contentStream.beginText();
        contentStream.setFont(pdfFont, fontSize);
        contentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount(startX, startY);

        for (String line : lines) {
            if(height>705){  //this is the height of my bottom line where I want cutoff. you can check yours by sysoout the content.
            line = line.trim();
            float charSpacing = 0;
            if (line.length() > 1) {
                float size = fontSize * pdfFont.getStringWidth(line) / 1000;
                float free = width - size;

                if (free > 0) {
                    charSpacing = free / (line.length() - 1);
                }
            }
            contentStream.drawString(line);
            contentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount(0, -leading);
            System.out.println("content Stream line :" + line);
            height--;
            System.out.println("value of height:"+ height);                          
                }

            else{
                contentStream.endText();
                contentStream.close();
                page = new PDPage(PDPage.PAGE_SIZE_A4);
                doc.addPage(page);
                contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page,false, true, true);
                contentStream.beginText();
                contentStream.setFont(pdfFont, fontSize);
                contentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount(startX, startY);
                System.out.println("Height counter value :"+ height);
                System.out.println("line insde the second page:" + line);
                contentStream.drawString(line);
                System.out.println("Output on second page:"+contentStream.toString());
                contentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount(0, -leading);  
                height=mediabox.getHeight() - 2 * margin; //

            }

        }
        contentStream.endText();
        contentStream.close();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

this is my configuration on the top for your reference how I am using.
happy coding ..

```
    PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page,true, true, true);
   //PDPage page1 = new PDPage(PDPage.PAGE_SIZE_A4);
    PDPageContentStream contentStream1 = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page,true, true, true);
    PDFont pdfFont = PDType1Font.COURIER;
    PDFont fontBold = PDType1Font.TIMES_BOLD;
    float leading = 1.5f * fontSize;
    PDRectangle mediabox = page.getMediaBox();
    float margin = 45;
    float width = mediabox.getWidth() - 2 * margin;
    float height = mediabox.getHeight() - 2 * margin;
    float startX = mediabox.getLowerLeftX() + margin - statVarX;
    float startY = mediabox.getUpperRightY() - margin - statVarY;
```