# How to add multiple pages in PDFBox

Tags: java, pdfbox

I want to write some content in my PDF using PDFBox. Once the page height is less than the margin I need to create another page. I want to retain the cursor information. I s there a way through which i can get the cursor information like where the cursor is present so i can subtract the margin from cursor position and add another page to it. Right now I have done something like this

```
PDRectangle rect = page.getMediaBox();
float positionY = rect.getWidth();
 positionY = positionY - pdfWriter.defaultBottomMargin;
if(positionY < positionX) {
               positionY = rect.getWidth();
                PDPage page2 = page;
               rect = page2.getMediaBox();
               document.addPage(page2);
               PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page2);
               contentStream.appendRawCommands("T*\n");
               contentStream.beginText();
              // contentStream.setFont(font, 12);
               contentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount(positionX, positionY);
               contentStream.drawString(tmpText[k]);
               contentStream.endText();
               contentStream.close();
               }
```

Comment: The "answer" by "Mr. Noddy" was probably meant to be a comment, but he doesn't have 50 points reputation. He tells you to look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18152803/how-do-you-track-the-location-of-pdpagecontentstreams-text-output . Btw, the answer to your question "Is there a way through which i can get the cursor information like where the cursor is present" is "no".

Comment: if an answer solved your problem, please press the green checkmark. If it isn't, mention in the comments why.

Answer (score 8):

You can use some class level variables like below which maintains positionY throught execution of pdf generation.

```
float PAGE_MARGIN = 20;
float newPagepositionY = page.findMediaBox().getHeight() - PAGE_MARGIN;
float positionY = newPagepositionY;
PDPage currentPage = new PDPage();
```

Before adding any content on PDF, check whether cursor has reached at end of page or not.
i.e. Create funtion as shown below

```
public boolean isEndOfPage(Row row) 
{
    float currentY = this.positionY ;
    boolean isEndOfPage = currentY  <= (PAGE_MARGIN + 10);

    return isEndOfPage;
}
```

Using above funtion, you can create new page as required.

```
if (isEndOfPage(row)) 
{
    // Reset positionY  to newPagepositionY
    this.positionY  = newPagepositionY;

    this.currentPage = new PDPage();

    // your code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```
package trypdf;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font;

public class PDF {

    public static PDPage blankPage= new PDPage();
    public  static float PAGE_MARGIN = 5;
    public static  float newPagepositionY = blankPage.getMediaBox().getHeight() - 
          PAGE_MARGIN;
    public static    float positionY = newPagepositionY;

    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException 
    {

          PDDocument document = new PDDocument();    

          // adding a new page to the document - the first page
          document.addPage(blankPage);   

          // creating the content that will appear on the previously added 
          //page 
          PDPageContentStream contentStream = new 
                      PDPageContentStream(document,blankPage); 

          //the begin of the text for the content
          contentStream.beginText();

          //formating the text   
          contentStream.setFont( PDType1Font.TIMES_ROMAN, 12 );
          contentStream.setLeading(14.5f);

          //setting the coordinates from where the text will be displayed 
          //on the page (first one is the column, second is for row)
          contentStream.newLineAtOffset(15, 750);

          //depending on the text formats you can get more or less rows on a 
          //page, for my formats I gor 49 rows + the document margins and 
          //the spaces between the rows; this goes for the first for
          for(int i=0; i<48;i++) {  

              //will display a text at the begining of every row in my case 
              //it will display the row number
              contentStream. showText(Integer.toString(i));

              //this for will display some text to each column of the page
              //in my case it will display the letter "a"+ one space 64 
              //times; depending on the text formats you can get more or 
              //less characters
              for(int j=0;j<63;j++) {
                  contentStream. showText("a"+" ");
              }

              //I wanted to display a "b" at each end of a line so I coud 
              //see that the line fits to the page
              contentStream. showText("b");

              //adds another line  
              contentStream.newLine();
          } 

          //marks the end of the text that will be displayed on the first 
          //page          
          contentStream.endText();

          //will close the content for the first page
          contentStream.close();

          //end of the first page

          //adding other 3 pages with the same text
          int j=0; //the counter for the pages that will be added

          while(j<3) {

                //adding another blank page to the document with different 
                //text from the previous one
                document.addPage(blankPage=new PDPage());

                //taking a content for the new page
                contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document,blankPage);
                contentStream.beginText(); 
                contentStream.setFont( PDType1Font.TIMES_ROMAN, 12 );
                contentStream.setLeading(14.5f);
                contentStream.newLineAtOffset(15, 720);

                //display a number for every row on the page
                for( int i=50; i<98;i++) {
                      contentStream. showText(Integer.toString(i));
                      contentStream.newLine();
                }

                //closing the text and the content
                contentStream.endText();
                contentStream.close();

                //increasing the counter for the page                  
                j++;
          }
          System.out.println("Content added");

          //Saving the document
          document.save("C:/PdfBox_Examples/docc1.pdf");  
          System.out.println("PDF created");  
          document.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you please explain the solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Imports
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFont;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font;

// Method to add a paragraph to a PDF document
public static void addParagraph(PDDocument document, String text, PDFont font, float fontSize, float margin) throws IOException {
  // Create a new page if the document is empty
  if (document.getNumberOfPages() == 0) {
    document.addPage(new PDPage());
  }
  
  // Get the current page and its content stream
  PDPage page = document.getPage(document.getNumberOfPages() - 1);
  PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page, PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.APPEND, true);
  
  // Set the text attributes
  contentStream.setFont(font, fontSize);
  contentStream.setLeading(fontSize * 1.2f); // Line spacing
  
  // Split the text into lines based on the page width and margin
  float pageWidth = page.getMediaBox().getWidth();
  float maxLineWidth = pageWidth - 2 * margin;
  List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
  int lastSpace = -1;
  while (text.length() > 0) {
    int spaceIndex = text.indexOf(' ', lastSpace + 1);
    if (spaceIndex < 0) {
      spaceIndex = text.length();
    }
    String subString = text.substring(0, spaceIndex);
    float subStringWidth = font.getStringWidth(subString) / 1000 * fontSize;
    if (subStringWidth > maxLineWidth) {
      if (lastSpace < 0) { // The word is longer than the line
        lastSpace = spaceIndex; // Break the word
      }
      subString = text.substring(0, lastSpace);
      lines.add(subString);
      text = text.substring(lastSpace).trim();
      lastSpace = -1;
    } else if (spaceIndex == text.length()) { // The last line
      lines.add(text);
      text = "";
    } else {
      lastSpace = spaceIndex;
    }
  }
  
  // Write the lines to the content stream
  contentStream.beginText();
  float pageHeight = page.getMediaBox().getHeight();
  float currentY = pageHeight - margin; // Start from the top margin
  for (String line : lines) {
    float lineWidth = font.getStringWidth(line) / 1000 * fontSize;
    float currentX = margin + (maxLineWidth - lineWidth) / 2; // Center the text horizontally
    if (currentY - fontSize < margin) { // No more space in the current page
      contentStream.endText();
      contentStream.close();
      page = new PDPage(); // Create a new page
      document.addPage(page);
      contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page, PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.APPEND, true); // Get its content stream
      contentStream.setFont(font, fontSize); // Set the text attributes again
      contentStream.setLeading(fontSize * 1.2f);
      contentStream.beginText();
      currentY = pageHeight - margin; // Reset the current Y position
    }
    contentStream.newLineAtOffset(currentX, currentY); // Move to the next line position
    contentStream.showText(line); // Show the line
    contentStream.newLine(); // Advance to the next line
    currentY -= fontSize * 1.2f; // Update the current Y position
  }
  
  // Close the content stream and save the document
  contentStream.endText();
  contentStream.close();
}
```